# Change background image of a button without extra buttons

Tags: ios

I've set a button with an image as it's background, and I'm trying to get the image to change back and forth from 2 different images when pressed. 
For example, a happy face when pressed would switch to a sad face, and when pressed again would switch back to a happy face and so on.

Any help you can offer would be amazing before I pull anymore hair out.

Answer (score 0):

set the images for two different states: normal and selected,
have the button target an action that toggles the selected state on the button/sender

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton* myButton;
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
    if(alreadySelected) {
        myButton.imageView.image = myNormalImage;
    } else {
        myButton.imageView.image = mySelectedImage;
    }
}
```

Not sure, but I think this should do it.

Answer (score 0):

What BoopMeister said, except as bshirley pointed out, you need this API call:

```
[myButton setImage:happyImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Could you help me make sense of this by making a cohesive comment which cover what to do as opposed to hopping between answers?:\