# change the background image of button in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I've a `UIButton` on cell of `UITableView` in my VC like this

```
arrowBtnUp = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
arrowBtnUp.frame = CGRectMake(50,(65-19)/2,31, 31);
[arrowBtnUp setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_up.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[arrowBtnUp addTarget:self action:@selector(slideAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:arrowBtnUp];
```

and this my `slideAction`

```
-(void) slideAction
{
    [arrowBtnUp setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_down.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // also tried  with UIControlStateSelected/Highlighted
}
```

But it didn't work.I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479301/change-background-image-of-a-button-without-extra-buttons) link but didn't help.
Any suggestion or sample would be appreciated.

Comment: What does not work? Is none of the images visible? Or is it not changed to arrow_down.png? Are you sure that slideAction is excecuted?

Comment: "didn't work" - more precisely?

Comment: Where is arrowBtnUp defined and/or stored and how to you get it into the cell? Is it visible in one cell only?

Comment: Are you sure you added arrow_down.png to your project ?

Comment: And how do you know slideAction was executed ?

Comment: Yes, slideAction is executed but button background image not changed to  arrow_down.png and arrowBtnUp is declared in .h file.

Comment: check if 
UIImage *btnImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_down.png"];
btnImg is not null;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should work.Anyways change your code like this and try

```
-(void) slideAction:(id)sender
{
   [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_down.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

and

```
[arrowBtnUp addTarget:self action:@selector(slideAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and ensure that you have arrow_down.png in your app bundle

Comment: Thanks its working, can you please explain what was wrong with my code?

Comment: im not sure but u must have added arrowBtnUp in multiple cells.If you can post your tableview delegate methods code then i'll be able to find out what actually went wrong

Comment: The point is that you defined arrowBtnUp somewhere. Probably in the .h file as you said. But which one? In order to complile it you must have it in your delegate, wich is usually the tableViewController. (Where the action is) But I guess that you never ever set the value of that variable properly. It is impossible if you have a number of cells showing this very button because the same (individual) UIView object cannot be in two cells at a time. Your action (slideAction:) does get passed the id of the very UIControl, that was pressed. And therefore you can access it properly.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is you are reusing the `arrowBtnUp` instance of UIButton.
Hence in the `slideAction` method you won't get the pressed buttons reference.

For getting the reference in the `slideAction` method you need to pass it as an argument.

So change the code like:

```
[arrowBtnUp addTarget:self action:@selector(slideAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


-(void) slideAction:(UIButton *)myButton
{
   [myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_down.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to change the button image after a touch, you should use the UIButton's control states. You can assign a background image for each "state" and let UIButton determine which to show.

Answer (score 0):

Background image is different than the icon on the button. Try this instead:

```
[_buttonConfirm setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"s.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to change the button image after a touch, you should use the UIButton's control states. You can assign a background image for each "state" and let UIButton determine which to show.

```
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_up.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_down.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

There is no need to manually switch the background images in your slideAction: target method.